# Difference between methods from Thread class and methods used with Thread.currentThread()?

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to start with doc from method currentThread():

> - Returns a reference to the currently executing thread object.
> - @return  the currently executing thread.

Now knowing this, it makes sense that **methods** such as `join()`, `isAlive()`, `getName()`, `isInterrupted()` etc. are called like this for example `Thread.currentThread().join`.

My question is how we don't need `currentThread` **prefix** to call **methods** such as `sleep()`, `yield()`, `interrupted()` etc? How can **static** call for example `Thread.sleep()` know exactly what **thread instance** are we 'targeting' when there is no **instance**?

Comment: Very good question! Hope someone can make a good answer. +1

Comment: @WJS I know that honestly. But why? Couldn't they make methods join, isAlive, getName.. static as well as they did for those 'last 3 methods'?

Comment: Nope.  For example.  getName() returns the name of the current thread.  But if getName were static, it wouldn't know which thread to return the name of.  If some information is required from the current thread instance, then you need an instance field.  For something that is simply shared (like sleep which is independent of an instance it can be static.

Comment: Makes sense :) But how would it know which thread to sleep for example? Remember sleep is static as well.

Comment: You're sleeping in the instance that you are presently in at the time.

Comment: That commend hit it right on point. Yet I have to ask this stupid question.If sleep() is used on instance 'presently on time', how come getName() can't do the same thing (for example: get me name of thread present in time)? Yet, there I would need currentThread prefix..

Comment: You can't sleep any thread but the current thread. You can get the name of any thread. You can join any thread *except,* in practice, the current thread. All the cases are different. One size does not fit all.

Comment: @Stefan  My answer was just a combined demo of the static sleep method and the thread specific getName() method (what we were discussing above).  The latter `captures` the thread so sleep can take effect on that thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can static call for example Thread.sleep() know exactly what thread instance are we 'targeting' when there is no instance?

They target the currently executing thread.

From the docs for [Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html):

> Causes the currently executing thread to sleep

The documentation for `yield` and `interrupted` etc also mention that they affect the current thread.

Regarding the comments about `join`, `getName` etc:

It doesn't make sense to make `join` static. If you did, the only thread you could join would be the current thread, which would immediately deadlock. You would be asking the current thread to wait for itself. `join` has to be non-static so you can tell it which thread to wait for (OK, you could have `static join(Thread threadToJoin)` but that's pretty cumbersome).

Sleep, and yield only make sense statically - you would never tell another thread to sleep or yield (you don't know what the other thread is doing - it might not be in a sensible state to sleep or yield). You only ever want to put yourself to sleep.

The other methods you mention in the comments could conceivably have static variants, but it makes more sense for them to be non-static because they provide information about the specific Thread object they are called on. You may notice that `interrupted` and `isInterrupted` are static and non-static, respectively, so there are cases where it makes sense to provide both. Is it worth having a static `getCurrentThreadName()` method? Probably not. We don't look for thread names very often, but checking for interruption is a very common operation so the convenience of not having to say `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` outweighs the cost of maintaining two methods.

Answer (score 1):

> why is for example `Thread.sleep()` written and not `Thread.currentThread().sleep()`

Because `sleep()` is not something that one thread should be able to do to a different thread.

`Thread.currentThread()` returns a reference to an *instance* of the `Thread` class. It's a special instance from the *caller's* point of view (i.e., it happens to be the `Thread` that called the function,) but from the language point of view, there's nothing special about it at all. It's *just* a thread.

That means, if you can call `Thread.currentThread().foo()`, then you can call `someOtherThread.foo()`.

Even if you were allowed to call `someOtherThread.sleep()`, it would be a very bad idea. That's why they made `sleep()` a `static` method that *implicitly* operates on the calling thread.

---

> My question is how we don't need `currentThread` **prefix** ...

OK, this is just my two cents worth, but if you think of `currentThread()` as some kind of a *prefix*, then I would advise you to spend more time learning the basics of the Java language before you dive into writing multi-threaded programs.